# multi regex to grab numbers in python

Tags: python, regex, show

I'm not expert with regex but I did this from scratch
I need to grab just numbers and letters [a-e] based on this :

```
SnnEnn   where n represent numbers  
SnnEnnl  where l = letter [a-e]  

nnXnn    where n represent numbers 
nnXnnl   where l = letter [a-e]
```

but it fails in few case like this:

```
02x01      match '02x01'                                      fail (It should be '02' '01')
03x02a     match '03x02'..............groups 'a'             fail (It should be '03' '02' 'a')
S03E01     match 'S03E01'.............groups '03'  '01'      ok
S03E01a    match 'S03E01a'............groups 'S03E01'  'a'   fail.(It should be '03' '01' 'a')

03x02xxxx  match '03X02xxxx' groups '03x02xxxx'    fail (it should be just [a-e] and limit to one letter) 
S03E01xxx  match '03E01xxxx' groups '03e01xxxx'    fail (idem)
```

[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/W0wjoq/1)

I'm using this regex :

```
(\d+[x]\d+\w)([a-e])|(\d+[x]\w+)|\bS(?P<Season>\d+)E(?P<Episode>\d+)|(\b[s]\d+[e]\d+)([a-e])
```

Thank for you for any help

Comment: Hi , that is an example. It means that it has to grab 'a-e' only and one time ( I need only one letter from a to e)

Comment: almost for the second regex (5zdiDU/1) , it shouldn't grab string like this : S03x01e because the 'x' , it should be always SnnEnn or nnXnn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use

```
\b(S)?(?P<Season>\d+)(?(1)E|x)(?P<Episode>\d+)(?P<Letter>[a-e]?)\b
```

- `\b` A word boundary
- `(S)?` Optionally capture `S` in group 1
- `(?P<Season>\d+)` Group `Season` - match 1+ digits
- `(?` Conditional (See [this page about conditionals](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-conditionals.html#syntax))

  - `(1)E` If group 1 exists, Match `E`
  - `|` Else
  - `x` Match `x`
- `)` Close conditional
- `(?P<Episode>\d+)` Group `Episode` - match 1+ digits
- `(?P<Letter>[a-e]?)` Group `Letter` -  match a range a-e
- `\b` A word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cP2pqH/1)

Comment: almost , it shouldn't match string like this : S03x01e because the 'x' , it should be always SnnEnn or nnXnn, where nn represent numbers

Comment: @JohnW You might use a conditional `\b(S)?(\d+)(?(1)E|x)(\d+)([a-e]?)\b` and the values are in group 2, 3 and 4 See https://regex101.com/r/QzpzLp/1

Comment: yes The fourth bird , it works . just a question :  '(?(1)E|x)'  Does it mean , if first char is 'S' then match 'E' else 'x' ?thank

Comment: @JohnW That is correct, See [this page](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-conditionals.html#syntax) for more information